# c# Tcp Listener give connected Client to Function ?

Tags: c#, tcp

How can i give the Timer Tick Funtion the TCP connected client Parameter?
Sure, client is not defined here.

```
  public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            string content = "Hello World!";
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            }
```

And in my main Void this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 8001);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Wait for clients");
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream()); in your DisplayTimeEvent event handler is not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make the client reference global.

```
static TcpClient client = null;
```

And in your main method:

```
client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Since your timer starts ticking only after the client reference  gets set (AcceptTcpClient method is blocking), you will be safe from NullReferenceExceptions in your timer method.

Comment: Okey this is mostly working :) But now i get this Error Message: In die Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten geschrieben werden: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen.(GERMAN)

Comment: Its saying: It cant write Datas to the Remoteconnection cause a existing Connection is canceled by a Hostcomputer (software controlled)

Comment: @Hanselman That means the connection has been dropped, which is another issue. You should look that up or post another question  related to that problem.

Comment: Okey i will reopen later a new Question :) Thanks